# Game Development Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a gamedev.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Game Development Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local gaming sessions or game dev conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: gamedev.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: He is supposed to be Turkish. Some say his father was German.

Comment: Nice - congrats to the moderators, you deserve it. (And kudos to SE staff, too).

Answer (score 5):

**Absolutely!** As you said, it would be handy to hand out at local game dev conferences or sessions.

I would probably even be willing to pay for them if you make the design and offer it through some sort of business card printing site. I'm proud to be a moderator here.

Answer (score 2):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!